# Which one is correct for the use of "input"?

Tags: nouns, verb-agreement

Which one of the two sentences below is correct?

1. The input **is** 20 apples.
2. The input **are** 20 apples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first choice. Replace "20 apples" with X and you'll see why that makes sense.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U.  Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).